# Generate annotation for features in ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, annotation

I need to programmatically generate annotations for features.  I don't need the actual annotation feature, just the text placement, size, angle, etc. properties that are generated.  Those attributes are going to be stored in a different file format.  Is there a way to generate anno on the fly in ArcObjects to get at these properties?

Answer (score 1):

I's all in the help file. Search the help for the following topic "Creating annotation and dimension feature classes". It describes the code you need for creating annotations using ArcObjects.

Comment: I ended up achieving this with the LabelPoint property on the features in my cursor.  I borrowed a simple algorithm from a script someone at my company wrote a while ago to calculate the angle, and luckily the size is static so that was easy.